# How configure Jest when using react-app-rewired and customize-cra?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, create-react-app

I am trying set up tests with `Jest` in a `create-react-app` that is using the `override` function from `customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired`. I have set up a relative path alias and when I run tests it throwing the error `cannot find module`

here is the code...

```
// LoginForm.test.js

import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';


it('submits', () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(<LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Log in'));
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

```
// config-overrides.js

const {
  override,
  fixBabelImports,
  addLessLoader,
  addBabelPlugin
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports("import", [
    {
      libraryName: "antd",
      libraryDirectory: "es"
      // style: true,
    },
    {
      libraryName: "ant-design-pro",
      libraryDirectory: "lib"
      // style: true,
    }
  ]),

  addBabelPlugin([
    "babel-plugin-root-import",
    {
      rootPathSuffix: "./src"
    }
  ]),

  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: {
      "@select-item-selected-font-weight": "500",
      "@font-family":
        '"Futura W01", "Futura", -apple -system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", sans-serif',
      "@pagination-font-family":
        '"Futura W01", "Futura", -apple -system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", sans-serif',
      "@statistic-font-family":
        '"Futura W01", "Futura", -apple -system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", sans-serif'
    }
  })
);
```

Any pointers much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is maybe a bit old but I just came across it and solved it so maybe it can help other people.

React app rewired uses react-scripts under the hood so it will not pick up your webpack configuration files. However there is a way to customize it, you can put your jest configuration in the root of your package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^@app(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/ui/app$1"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
       "<rootDir>/config/jest/setupTests.js"
    ]
}
```

You can see that react-script is picking up this config if you go to the source code of react-scripts/scripts/test and see that it is creating the jest config:

`const createJestConfig = require('./utils/createJestConfig');`

And that file overrides the default configuration with the jest config in your package.json:

`const overrides = Object.assign({}, require(paths.appPackageJson).jest);`

Where paths.appPackageJson is your package.json

Comment: The problem is this merges your Jest config in `package.json` with the default config. In my case this is a problem because I need `transformIgnorePatterns` to be an empty array

Answer (score 2):

As tests don't go via webpack the path aliases won't work. However, they do go through Babel so you can use `babel-plugin-module-resolver'. Normally you'd do it like this:

```
// .babelrc
{
"plugins": [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "root": ["./src"],
    "alias": {
      "test": "./test",
      "components": "./src/components"
    }
  }]
 ]
}
```

But looking at`override` above it looks like this might work:

```
addBabelPlugin([
  "babel-plugin-root-import",
  {
    rootPathSuffix: "./src"
  },
  "module-resolver",{
      "root": ["./src"],
       "alias": {
          "test": "./test",
          "components": "./src/components"
       }
   }
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .babelrc, I made that way

Read the [README.md of react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#:%7E:text=A%20lot%20of%20the%20time%20you%27ll%20be%20able%20to%20make%20the%20configuration%20changes%20needed%20simply%20by%20using%20a%20combination%20of%20the%20package.json%20file%27s%20jest%20section%20and%20a%20.babelrc%20file) , it helped me a lot.

```
// for jest 
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-root-import",
            {
                "rootPathSuffix": "src"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

It for

"babel-plugin-root-import": "~6.4.1"
"customize-cra": "~0.9.1"
"react": "~16.8.6"